# TC should be the right-hand operand in Java 8 Language Specification

Tags: java

If we look at Java 8 Language Specification [§15.26.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1)

> - Otherwise, the value of the index subexpression is used to select a component of the array referred to by the value of the array reference subexpression.
>
> > **This component is a variable; call its type SC**. Also, **let TC be the type of the left-hand operand of the assignment operator** as determined at compile time. Then there are two possibilities:
> >
> > > - If TC is a primitive type, then SC is necessarily the same as TC.
> > >
> > > The value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the selected array component, is subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the array component.

1. It says that **"let TC be the type of the left-hand operand of the assignment operator"**, so TC is the left operand and SC is the component of array and is the type of right operand.

So, the code goes like this:

`int TC = 15;`
`int[] SC = {1,2,3,4,5};`
`TC = SC[0];`

2. Next is the weird things, it says that **"the value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the selected array component"**

> Execution 1: The value of of the right-hand operand `SC[0]` is 1. 
>   Execution 2: Then 1 is converted to the type of the selected array component `SC[0]`. 
>   Execution 3: 1 is converted to int.

3. **"and the result of the conversion is stored into the array component"**

> Execution 4: 1 is stored back in the `SC[0]`.

if we follow that step, the code:

`TC = SC[0];`

is never happened, because `SC[0]` is stored back to itself.

It should says that :

> - Otherwise, the value of the index subexpression is used to select a component of the array referred to by the value of the array reference subexpression.
>
> > **This component is a variable; call its type SC**. Also, **let TC be the type of the right-hand operand of the assignment operator** as determined at compile time. Then there are two possibilities:
> >
> > > - If TC is a primitive type, then SC is necessarily the same as TC.
> > >
> > > The value of the right-hand operand is converted to the type of the selected array component, is subjected to value set conversion (§5.1.13) to the appropriate standard value set (not an extended-exponent value set), and the result of the conversion is stored into the array component.

so the code like this:

`int TC = 15;`
`int[] SC = {1,2,3,4,5};`
`SC[0] = TC;`

would run, and the value of `TC` is stored into `SC[0]`

My question: Am I right?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Okay.. but thats not a question..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have misread the context for this section of the JLS.

The section you are quoting from starts with

> If the left-hand operand is an array access expression (§15.10.3), possibly enclosed in one or more pairs of parentheses

The array is on the left hand side, as in

```
t[0] = 1;
```

I'm not sure why you think it implies otherwise, but it is always and explicitly dealing with assignment to array elements.

The particular problem this clause is addressing is:

```
interface TC {};

class SC implements TC {};

class RC implements TC {};

TC[] tcArray = new SC[1];
tcArray[0] = new RC();
```

That code (ignoring syntax shortcuts) compiles, but is required to fail at runtime with an `ArrayStoreException`.

Comment: no, a class cannot extends an interface

Comment: Fine, I switched my rough example code to be more syntacticly correct. But if you're genuinely interested in getting an answer to your question, then you might want to focus on something more consequential than a typo in a simple example.